# selecting top column1 with matching column2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

sorry for asking this, but i'm runnin' out of ideas

i have this table:

```
[id]    [pid]    [vid]
1        4        6844
1        5        6743
2        3        855
2        6        888
...
```

how to i query this eg.table to get the following result:

```
[id]    [pid]    [vid]
1        5        6743
2        6        888
```

i want to get the highest [pid] for an [id] with the [vid] matching to this [pid]

any ideas?

i'm using mssql 2008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use Common Table Expressions (CTE). This offers lots of possibilities like so:

```
WITH Result (RowNumber, [id], [pid], [vid])
AS
(
    SELECT Row_Number() OVER (PARTITION BY [id]
                              ORDER     BY [vid] DESC)
          ,[id]
          ,[pid]
          ,[vid]
      FROM MyTable
)
SELECT [id]
      ,[pid]
      ,[vid]
  FROM Result
 WHERE RowNumber = 1
```

Comment: as your solution provides more options, i'll give you the point!

Answer (score 4):

one way

```
select t1.* from
(select id,max(pid) as Maxpid
from yourtable
group by id) t2
join yourtable t1 on t2.id = t1.id
and t2.Maxpid = t1.pid
```

Comment: sorry for depriving you the points :) but Bliek's solution is much more comfortable and offers a lot more of options...

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using Microsoft SQL Server 2008, then I'd recommend [Common Table Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx) and [the OVER clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx) to accomplish dividing the results into groups by **id**, and returning just the top row in each group (ordered by **pid**). Bliek's answer shows one way to do that.

(This same basic approach, by the way, is very useful for more efficient paging, as well.)

There isn't a fantastically great way to do this with "standard" SQL. The method show in SQLMenace's answer will only work in databases where you can use a subquery as a table. It'd be one way to accomplish this in SQL Server 2000, for example, but may not work in every mainstream RDBMS.